# Xcode 6 Adaptive Storyboard different Segues per Device

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, adaptive-ui

I've some troubles with the newly introduced adaptive storyboard in Xcode 6.
The iPhone App is finished and now I want to create a universal app out of it.
Let's assume I've a `viewcontroller` that displayes some cells and a detail `viewcontroller` in which the details of the cells are displayed.

On iPhone: When I click the cell I've a `push segue` to the detail view.
On iPad: I would like to have a `modal segue` instead of a push.

Can I change this in the `prepareForSegue` or somehow else?

**EDIT: 
I found a way... but I'm not fully happy with it. If someone has a better solution, please tell me...**

I made two segues and distinguish it in the code.

```
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(kSegueToDetailModal, sender: object)
    }
    else if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(kSegueToDetail, sender: object)
    }
```

Comment: Why not creating 2 different storyboards, one for iPhone and one for iPad?

Comment: This option doesn't exist anymore in Xcode 6.1

Comment: yes, use different storyboard, check my example (I’m not ussing any code) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19438780/test2Storyboard.zip

Comment: Don't use a different storyboard, that's totally missing the point of adaptivity.

Comment: I showed an example, how to use different storyboards in Xcode 6 .. but my recommendation also it's to use only one.. with Size Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two segues and distinguish in code as you suggest, but I recommend using adaptive size classes to determine which segue you want rather than the `userInterfaceIdiom`. This way you could also use the modal segue with, for example, the iPhone 6 Plus in landscape orientation as well as iPad.